# Access error setuping Multiple Domains in nginx

Tags: nginx

I try to setup Multiple Domains in nginx under ubuntu 18
I created new directory with index file:

```
mkdir /var/www/test.com
cd /var/www/test.com
sudo nano /var/www/test.com.index.html
```

with some text text

> /var/www/test.com.index.html page sample

I create config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/modules-available/test.com
```

with text:

```
server {

   listen 80;

   root /var/www/test.com;

   index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

   server_name test.com;

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ = 404;
   }

}
```

and in hosts:

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

add 1 line :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost test.com
```

I create symbol link :

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/modules-available/test.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

and Check it I see test.com:

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
ls

sudo service nginx restart
```

check :

```
curl test.com
```

I got :

```
$ curl test.com
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

but not sample text I enreed above.

File /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is default and has lines :

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

1) Why error and how to fix it ?

2) I suppose I need to disable /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file. How can I do it ?

**Modified :**

I run

```
cd /var/www/  # (it root of all aps)
sudo chown -R www-data: .
```

and restarting with

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.2-fpm
sudo service nginx restart
```

It did not help , I have the same error ...
Can it be some option or misspelling in modules-available/test.com ?

Comment: If you create your index.html file using `sudo`, the nginx won't be able to execute it because it own by `root`.

Comment: How can it be salved?

Comment: `cd /var/www/HTML` and run `sudo chown -R www-data: .` to change all the files in the directory to be owned by nginx.

Comment: Did you create a file at `/var/www/test.com.index.html` or `/var/www/test.com/index.html`?

Comment: Please, look at Modified